# split a page into 2 halfs(top and bottom)

Tags: html

I want to split a page into 2 halves(not as a column) but as a row(top and bottom) and give 2 colors one for top and one for bottom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2870276)

**html:**

```
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

**css:**

```
#top,
#bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50%;
}

#top {
    top: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}

#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Demo:** [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vznAr/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div style="height:100%">
<div class="topdiv">top div</div>
<div class="bottomdiv">bottom div</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
div.topdiv {clear:both;position:fixed;top:0;height:50%;width:100%;background-color:#990000;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:16px;text-align:center;}
div.bottomdiv {clear:both;position:fixed;bottom:0;height:50%;width:100%;background-color:#009900;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:16px;text-align:center;}​
```